# Is there any simpler approach to provided a default value for un-suppiled or blank string field when parsing JSON with argonaut?

Tags: json, scala, argonaut

I'm using Argonaut to parse JSON strings. There is a requirement: If any field is not provided, or is empty or blank, give it the string "not supplied" instead.

I have a solution, but it seems very complicated:

```
case class User(name: String, home: String)

implicit def UserDecodeJson: DecodeJson[User] = DecodeJson(j => for {
  name <- (j --\ "name").as[BlankAsNonSupplied]
  home <- (j --\ "home").as[BlankAsNonSupplied]
} yield User(name.value, home.value))

case class BlankAsNonSupplied(value: String)

implicit def BlankAsNonSuppliedDecodeJson: DecodeJson[BlankAsNonSupplied] = DecodeJson.withReattempt(a => {
  val v = a.success.map(_.focus).flatMap(_.string)
    .filterNot(_.trim.isEmpty)
    .map(BlankAsNonSupplied.apply).getOrElse(BlankAsNonSupplied("not supplied"))
  DecodeResult.ok(v)
})
```

You can see the `BlankAsNonSuppliedDecodeJson` one is very complicated, and hard to understand. Is there any way to make it(or the whole example) simpler?